# Does my code work for accessor and mutator methods?

Tags: java, syntax, mutators, textpad

I am supposed to do a project where I declare and instantiate 5 empty card slots called myHand using arrays, and I will need an advanced mutator method that sets a single card into the hand, and an advanced accessor that gets a card from myHand. Does the following code work for all of above? Please know that Card is from another class called Card.java where all card values, suits, etc. are completed

```
private Card[] myHand;
private int numberHand;  //counts number of card in hand
private int numberDealt; //counts number of cards dealt onto the table

public void setCard(int I, Card c)
{
    myHand[I]=c;
    numberHand++;
}

public Card getCard()
{
   Card tempCard = myHand[numberDealt];
   numberDealt++;
   return tempCard;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your homework it's not possible to determine if your code does what it's supposed to.

Comment: If the `get()` method does take an `int` parameter, why would the `set()` method do that? Don't you think the `set()` method should use the `numberHand` for the array index, similar to how `get()` uses `numberDealt` for the array index?